# Can I set a texture as the wallpaper of an iOS device?

Tags: unity, ios

I have a game in Unity which creates drawings.

I need to have a button which sets the drawing as the wallpaper (with permission from the user of course).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no public API available to set the wallpaper or lock screen images of an iOS device(*).

You can [save the picture to the user's camera roll](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW29) and provide instructions for them to manually change the wallpaper, but you can't actually do it all yourself.

(*) It seems like it should be possible to do this on a *jailbroken* device, however (some cursory searching suggests by writing to `/var/mobile/Library/LockBackground.jpg` for example). But unless you're targeting jailbroken devices you're out of luck.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case but had to be sure. Thank you.